# In which site should I post a question related to the configuration of an SSL Certificate

Tags: discussion

Where should I post my question

I want to configure an SSL Certificate while hosting a react application on my home web server.

I posted it on https://security.stackexchange.com/
but it has been declared off-topic

Comment: "I want to configure an SSL Certificate" What does that mean exactly? It is ambiguous. Is it about GETTING a certificate? Then it could be on topic of [su] for example, depending which routes you go to get one, what errors you have, etc. Is it about USING a given certificate in your server, website or else? Then it could be on topic for [sf] maybe, but in all cases, look in the Help section to see what is ontopic or not. There might not be ANY forum where it is ontopic (besides seeing lots of old questions themselves offtopic), StackExchange is not exhaustive.

Comment: And if it is about running your website with a given certificate and having problems or errors it might be ontopic for [webmaster.se].